# Binomial theorem, prove an expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Forgive me guys, i don't really know how to edit this so it would look like 'maths' but i really don't understand what this is asking me to do -_-

Use the Binomial Theorem to show that:

$$
0 = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k
$$

Comment: Your formula is only for $n>0$, because if $n=0$ then the right-hand side is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Look at $(1-1)^n$ ${}{}$

Comment: but when n is 0, we get 0 to the power of 0 which is undefined

Comment: Since the proposed formula is true only for $n \ge 1$, this "not defined" case is irrelevant.

Comment: I've worked this out on paper - it does work but i don't understand why we can safely say that 0 = (1-1)^n

Comment: @DoctorR $(1-1) = 0$ and $0^n = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: but k starts from 0, doesn't that mean that n = 0?

Comment: @DoctorR, where the sum starts is irrelevant, you are interested in where it ends. And if the case $n = 0$ is of interest, handle it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How would you use binomial theorem to expand $(1+ (-1))^n$

Comment: I see, but why is it safe to say that 0 = (1+(-1))^n? values of k start at 0 so n could be 0 couldn't it?

Comment: The statement doesnt really make sense for n=0 but for all n>0 it works